# Python - Exception in thread Thread-1 (in __bootstrap_inner)

Tags: python, typeerror, traceback

I have built a python script that manages a bunch of different things for my pool. I have been adding more functions and playing with some timeouts on my Raspberry Pi that is running everything. Today I started getting this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

So I started reading up on the last part (TypeError: 'str" object is not callable and figured I must have used it as a variable and it was interfering with the built-in str function. So I looked for every single instance if str in my code I could find (1300 lines) and this is all that I have found, so now I am stumped as to what could actually be causing the problem (shortened to show where the str is:

```
1) logger.info("Notify socket = {0}".format(str(s_adr)))
2) ph_value = str(line)
3)"/input/post.json?&node=" + str(pooldb.ph_node)
4) orp_value = str(line2)
5)"/input/post.json?&node=" + str(pooldb.orp_node)
6) current_military_time = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M'))
```

That is it, in 1300+ lines of code those are the only instances of 'str' that I can find and none of them are variables so I am confused as to what is causing the error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has nothing to do with the `str()` builtin.  The message is telling you that `self.function` is of *type* `str` - and strings in fact are not callable.  Like so:

```
>>> 'ab'(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> 23(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> [7](3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

You should look instead at how you're creating threads.  For example,

```
>>> import threading
>>> t = threading.Thread(target="abc")
>>> t.start()
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: OK, here is the way I am calling the thread:

    `import threading` 
    `threading.Timer(pooldb.checktime, pool_level).start()`

Comment: Nobody here is telepathic ;-)  That is, nobody can guess what `pooldb.checktime` and `pool_level` are.  If. e.g., `pool_level` is bound to a string, then the error you're seeing is exactly what you should be seeing.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My apologies, I am not really sure what you need to see to help out. pool_level is an entire function. It is shown at line 1255 here: [link](https://github.com/rjsears/Pool_Fill_Control/blob/master/pool_fill_control.py) and pooldb.checktime is on line 94 here: [link](https://github.com/rjsears/Pool_Fill_Control/blob/master/pooldb.py)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not willing to stare at over 1000 lines of code, and I doubt anyone else will be either.  I gave you this link before:  . http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   Reduce to the simplest possible code reproducing the problem that anyone can run, and then you'll get help quickly.  Your original question revealed almost nothing, while posting a link to the entire project reveals way too much ;-)

Comment: BTW, try logging `repr(pool_level)` on the line just before you create the `Timer`.  If `pool_level` is in fact being rebound to a string (which would explain everything), that will provide a huge clue, namely the _value_ of the string it got rebound to.